# After refreshing page ajax loaded content disapear and it shows main page contents

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to load some pages in my index.html using ajax but after loading ajax content sucesfully when i try to refresh index.html then it shows index.html page content conly and then i need to click on link to load ajax again.

here is what i'm trying to

```
<!-- Loading Content -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function load_pages(url) {
                $('#project').html('<p><img src="../images/loader/ajax-loader1.gif" width="100" height="19" style="margin: 30% auto 0px 30%;"/></p>');
                /*$('#product-content').load(url);*/

                /*setTimeout(2000);*//*For Checking loading image*/

                $('#project').load(url, "",
                        function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                            if (textStatus === 'error') {
                                $('#project').html('<p style="margin: 30% auto 0 30%;">Unable to load the content...</p>');
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        </script>
        <!-- Loading Content End -->



<a href="javascript:void 0" onclick="load_pages('project-1/location.html');">Location</a></li>
```

here is my problem video

http://youtu.be/RB_NYPwkrsE

Comment: That's the reason it's called ajax.(Displaying results without refresh).

Comment: but what if i wanted to refresh fresh dynamic content in ajax????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it happens, because browser refreshes cache memory when the pages refresh and go to its intial postion.
if you still want to remain the ajax page loaded, then you must enter an entry to the database, and check by it is loaded or not if value says it is already loaded. then you call your ajax on pageload.
its the only solution according to me.

Comment: yes that can be a solution for one ajax but i have more than one pages so i need to more entry for database is there any alternative bro

Comment: take a field in database pageLoaded, and insert it values 1 if 1 loaded page1 loaded, and 2 if page2 loaded.
manage it according to your need and by your logic